# Getting a continous prediction even though output layer is sigmoid

Tags: keras, binary, lstm

Below is my code. I'm looking to get a direction prediction on price. I understand from various tutorials it is my output layer that needs to be in Sigmoid to obtain a binary prediction.

However, even though I have done so as below, my prediction still comes out as a continuous?

```
model = Sequential()

# Add first layer with dropout regularisation with 100 neurons and inputs shape for 1st set
model.add(LSTM(units=256, input_shape = (data.shape[1],data.shape[2]), return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Add second layer with dropout
model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Add a Dense layer 
model.add(Dense(64,  activation ='relu'))

# Add the output layer #as we are predicting direction, we use the sigmoid activation function
model.add(Dense(1,  activation ='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: if pred > 0.5 is 1 else is 0

Comment: thats it??? :( Thank you!!